# Nested property expansion in SoapUI

Tags: xquery, soapui

Short version: How do I do nested property expansion in an XQuery in SoapUI Pro 5, where the outer property is a reference to the ResponseAsXML of a previous test step, and the inner property comes from a properties file?

Example:

My test steps look like this:

1. Call AddCustomer, which also adds an email address, and returns customerId.
2. Use property transfer to store the customerId in a properties file called EmailProperties.
3. Call AddEmailToCustomer, which adds a second email to the same customer and returns a new emailId.
4. Call GetEmailsForCustomer, which returns both emails for the customer.

The REST endpoints for step 3 and 4 look like this:

```
POST/GET http://myEndpoint.com/customers/{customerId}/emails
```

When trying to verify step 4, I wrote an XQuery that loops through the Response (since we can't guarantee what order the emails will be in the response) to find the email added in step 3.  In my XQuery, if I hardcode the customerId in the namespace like this it works fine:

```
for $email in //emails
where $email/id/text()='${AddEmailToCustomer#ResponseAsXml#declare namespace ns1='http://myEndpoint.com/customers/1234/emails'; //ns1:Response[1]/ns1:id[1]}'
```

But if I try to use the customerId from the properties file like this:

```
for $email in //emails
where $email/id/text()='${AddEmailToCustomer#ResponseAsXml#declare namespace ns1='http://myEndpoint.com/customers/${#EmailProperties#customerId}/emails'; //ns1:Response[1]/ns1:id[1]}'
```

I get an error about how it can't find the expected child nodes:

```
...Exception:org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff[different] Expected presence of child nodes to be 'true' but was 'false'...
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wildcards for namespaces to greatly simplify your XPaths:

```
where $email/id/text()='${AddEmailToCustomer#ResponseAsXml#//*:Response[1]/*:id[1]}'
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks!  I didn't realize I could use wildcards for the namespace :)

Answer (score 0):

As @SiKing recommends you can use wildcards for namespaces to simplify XPath, this is enough if you don't care about check the namespace (which is the most usual behavior). However I think that you put the namespace in a property in order to check possible different namespaces due you can try declaring your XQuery Match assertion as follows:

```
declare namespace ns1='http://myEndpoint.com/customers/${#EmailProperties#customerId}/emails';
<XQueryResult>
{
 for $email in //ns1:emails
 where $email/id/text()='${AddEmailToCustomer#Response#//ns1:Response[1]/ns1:id[1]}'
 return $email
}
</XQueryResult>
```

Please note that if `EmailProperties` is a property testStep then you must use `${EmailProperties#customerId}` instead of `${#EmailProperties#customerId}`, also in this case I prefer to use `#Response` instead of `#ResponseAsXml`.

Hope this helps,

Comment: SiKing's answer worked for this test case, but I will keep yours in mind if I do ever need to deal with multiple namespaces!  Thanks!